# Convert Base64 to Image file and save file directory : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, image, user, convert

How to **convert base 64 image format to image file and save image in local file directory** in magento 2

```
  public function setProfileImage($customerId, $base64)
        {
             if ($customerId) {
                     //code for convert base64 to image file and save file directory
                  } 

        }
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: for custom image upload???

Comment: yes , actually i need for api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001163/9956270 check this link And You Can convert base64_decode($img); like this

Comment: @RkRathod  not works for me

Comment: any error ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function setProfileImage($customerId, $base64, $name)
    {
        if ($customerId) {

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
            $mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
            $media = $mediaPath . 'customer/profile_image/';

            $data = $base64;
            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
            list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
            $data = base64_decode($data);
            if (file_put_contents($media . $name . uniqid() . '.png', $data)) {
                return 'success';
            } else {
                return 'failed';
            }
        }
    }
```